# How to get status and Azure databox report? How many Storage accounts I can use in a one Azure databox?

Tags: azure-databoxfamily

Azure Data Box service natively provides reports that you can use for your chain of custody documentation. The audit and copy logs are available in your storage account in Azure and you can [download the order history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databox/data-box-portal-admin#download-order-history) in the Azure portal after the order is complete.

What type of reporting is available to support chain of custody?

Following reporting is available to support chain of custody:

- Transport logistics from UPS.
- Logging of powering on and user share access.
- BOM or manifest file with a 64-bit cyclic redundancy check (CRC-64) or checksum for each file ingested successfully into the Data Box.

A maximum of **10** **storage accounts**, general purpose, classic, or blob storage are supported with Data Box. Both hot and cool blob are supported

Data Box pricing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/databox/
You are billed when the order has reached a terminal state (i.e the order has completed without errors)
The pricing for Azure Data Box is based on the amount of data you transfer to Azure. The cost is calculated based on the amount of data you transfer to Azure, the type of Data Box you use, and the shipping method you choose. You can find more information on the Azure Data Box pricing page.

Note: Seeding question